# Log writing of a application being ported to Bluemix

Tags: java, logging, log4j, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty

We have an existing application whose functionality we are trying to port to Bluemix. The existing application is using SL4J + log4j 2.0 to perform application logging. What is the suggested way of logging from a Java application in Bluemix and the most performant one?

And do we have some provision of DailyRollingFileAppender logging in Bluemix? 
Currently the application is using the trigger based policy to generate the 4 hours files provided by log4j 2.0.
These logs will be kept in the system for a certain duration, for Audit Trail purpose.

Answer (score 2):

A good practice for logging on Bluemix java applications is to write the log to stdout and use a loggregator drain the logs. You can also use services like log Analysis for long term persistence. 
You can configure third party services, Splunk or Papertrail for example, to drain your logs from loggregator.
Have a look on http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/services/log-management-thirdparty-svc.html

Other great solution could be Monitoring and analysis plugin service, to save and track logs.

Comment: Stdout is normally a non performant option, can you highlight some architectural consideration why this from cloud perspective is the Best option chosen ?